# Android Studio 4.0 seems to insert random garbage into layout files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I recently upgraded to Android Studio version 4.0. I have started seeing strange behavior whereby layout files get corrupted with seemingly random text. This text is not anything I have typed anywhere in the project.

Why is this happening and what to do about it?

I have done "invalidated caches / restart" several times. Doesn't help. Fortunately I have version control so can recover the damaged files, but this has happened 4 times in the last hour!

[image]

Comment: What's interesting is that the color-coding of the file in the Explorer tree suggests that it is not modified from what you have in version control (black vs. blue). If you examine the file from outside of the IDE, is it really changed?

Comment: Mark - from other comments I googled and found from prior versions, it does seem like the source on disk would have been ok. But reverting back from VCS also worked, and I think it turned out to be a plugin that wasn't ready for the 4.0 upgrade. Lesson learned, I'll be checking all add plugins prior to upgrading from here on out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Android Studio 4 since the beta version came out, and I've had no issues.

This might happen if you have any plugins installed, that might still not be compatible with this newer version.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe. I installed one previously called "Statistic". Maybe that's the culprit. I'll uninstall it and see what I get.

Comment: I haven't had another occurrence since I removed that plugin, that must have been it, thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Good to know 